# Какой вариант кода чище и правильнее?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Что лучше, 3 раза просто вызвать эту функцию и все, либо пустить её через цикл и чтобы она там 3 раза вызвалась и во время цикла, через условия заменять значения на каждой итерации, я понимаю, делаю одно и тоже, только еще условия добавляя, но все же, что более чище и читабельнее и грамотнее??

1 вариант или 2?

```
public function setAgrClause($data)
{
 //1 вариант
    $classIsn = 198390;
    $clauseIsn = 11110;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        if ($i > 0) {
            $classIsn = 5377;
            $clauseIsn = 2999;
        }
        if ($i > 1) {
            $classIsn = 471491;
            $clauseIsn = 471481;
        }
        $this->kias->setAgrClause($this->userIsn, $data['agrISN'], $classIsn, $clauseIsn);
    }

//2 вариант
    
    $this->kias->setAgrClause($this->userIsn, $data['agrISN'], 198390,  11110);
    $this->kias->setAgrClause($this->userIsn, $data['agrISN'],  5377,  2999);
    $this->kias->setAgrClause($this->userIsn, $data['agrISN'], 471491, 471481);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Лично я голосую за 2 вариант, потому что в 1 варианте дольше разбираться что вообще происходит

Comment: Я тоже, второй вариант выглядит читабельнее и корректнее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первый вариант это вообще что-то с чем-то. Явная попытка натянуть сову на глобус. Зачем так запутывать код - вообще не понятно.

Если вас напрягает то что у вас идут подряд три вызова одного и того же метода, но с разными параметрами и хочется сделать цикл и красиво, то логичнее использовать массив с данными и уже на его основе делать цикл.

Как-то так, например,

```php
$params = [
  ['classIsn' =>198390,  'clauseIsn' => 11110],
  ['classIsn' =>5377,  'clauseIsn' => 2999],
  ['classIsn' =>471491,  'clauseIsn' => 471481],
];

foreach($params as $isn) {
  $this->kias->setAgrClause(
    $this->userIsn, 
    $data['agrISN'], 
    $isn['classIsn'],  
    $isn['clauseIsn']
  );
}
```

Следующим шагом по рефакторингу, может быть вариант, когда этот массив определяется не в методе, а передается в качестве параметра. Т.е. сам по себе метод становится независимым от всякого рода магических констант. Ну и потом для расширения системы есть место куда расти. Может быть потом сделаете чтобы эти параметры брались из конфигруационного файла или из базы данных. И таим образом изменение чисел не приведет к правкам кода.

Comment: благодарю, выглядит чище и читабельнее, чем те 2 моих варианта, про 1 вариант, вы правы, это был первый тестовый вариант, который в голову пришел)

Comment: а как быть в случае, если появляется 3 параметр, который не используется в 1-х двух вызовах метода, а. в третьем он добавляется, а в остальных пустой, через условие пойти в таком случае?

Comment: Так есть null - там где не используется, там null, где используется, там уже значение. Ну или что у вас там будет по умолчанию в вызываемом методе для данного параметра.